# How to use the allowjaggedrows argument with bq_table_upload

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, bigrquery

I want to load CSVs from a Google Cloud Storage via `bq_table_upload` into a BigQuery table. The CSVs can have different columns. Therefore I want to use the `allowjaggedrows` argument (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options).

As you can read in the documentation for `bq_table_upload`, via `...` additional arguments can be passed to the underlying API.

> Additional arguments passed on to the underlying API call. snake_case names are automatically converted to camelCase.

My exemplary use case:

The following two CSVs are located in a GCS folder.

**test_1.csv**

| date | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | a |
| 2022-02-02 | 2 | b |

**test_2.csv**

| date | foo | bar | lorem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-03 | 3 | c | x |
| 2024-04-04 | 4 | d | y |

I define the fields as follows.

```
fields <- as_bq_fields(list(
  bq_field(name = "date", type = "DATE", mode = "required"),
  bq_field(name = "foo", type = "INT64"),
  bq_field(name = "bar", type = "STRING"),
  bq_field(name = "lorem", type = "STRING")
))
```

I create a partitioned table as follows.

```
bq_table_create(
  x = "my-project.my-dataset.my-table",
  fields = fields,
  timePartitioning = list(timepartitioning = list(type='DAY', field= 'date'))
)
```

This works as expected.

[image]

I am trying to load the two CSVs as follows.

```
bq_table_load(
  x = "my-project.my-dataset.my-table",
  source_uris = "gs://my-bucket/subfolder/*.csv",
  source_format = "CSV",
  nskip = 1,
  create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
  write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
  allow_jagged_rows = TRUE
)
```

This fails with the following error.

```
Error in `bq_job_wait()`:
! Job 'my-project.job_JM9xfaHoSqUHQgTagI_cjidNZ8qj.europe-west3' failed
✖ Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 2; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0 [invalid]
```

In the load job details I get the following error details.

[image]

When I click on *Repeat load job*, I can see, that the *Jagged rows* option is not checked.

[image]

When I select the option and run the job via browser interface, the CSVs are loaded correctly.

[image]

Therefore I assume that the argument is not passed.

Have you also observed this problem? Do I need to specify the argument in a different way in `bq_table_load`? Or am I misunderstanding how the function works?